# How to show 4 videos at once using Google Cardboard?

Tags: android, video, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, 360-virtual-reality

I am trying to show four videos at once using Google Cardboard. These videos are normal 2D videos that were shot on a normal 16:9 camera. What I want and need is to have one video in front of you then you turn your head 90 degrees and you see another video, turn again and see another until you hit the front video again. Please see my Pablo Picasso Microsoft Paint skills to visualize what I am talking about...[image]
So basically what I need is like four VR movie theater screens that a person can look around in. Is there a program I could use or do I have to do some programming to make this happen? Searching this is not easy with all the articles of VR that pop up. Any help that can point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Similar to the Netflix virtual living room - see this article which may help (or may scare you!): http://techblog.netflix.com/2015/09/john-carmack-on-developing-netflix-app.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found an app that did this all for me. The app is called 360 Virtual Reality Player(Google Play Store) and it takes any 2D video and makes it into a head-tracked VR video. Once I found this app, all I needed to do is stitch the videos together with a black bar in between them using OpenCV to get the desired effect.